# How to utilize DIV tags to work like Table Columns

Tags: html

please refer to the picture to get a better visual idea.
I do not have access to Table element because the free edition of the framework I am using "ZK framework" does not have tables but it has DIV .
so think of a Table with some rows and three columns: I used a DIV tag with Left Margin and drew the elements of my left column..

```
<div id="leftColumn" width= "45%" align="left" style = "margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:30px;margin-left:20px;">
```

I am thinking of using the second column of this table for the spacing between elements on each row and using the third column to put my right hand side elements on it...
so now for the other two DIVs how should I set its properties to look correct?
and actually do you have any better design thoughts?

Thank you. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.divsYouNeedToColumn { display: inline }
```

in your css should solve your problems.
By the way, the framework restricting tables seems very... stupid.

Comment: what does mean .divsYouNeedToColumn ?  can you please write a Inline CSS version of it for now?

Comment: Let's say you have your HTML like this:


    <div id="container">
        <div id="leftColumn" class="column" various attributes></div>
        <div id="columnSeparator" class="column" various attributes></div>
        <div id="rightColumn" class="column" various attributes></div>
    </div>

Your css would look like this: 

.column {
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
}